# update the record from where it came actually

Tags: c#, asp.net

In gridview I need to display the records from two different tables like: `t1 table` and `t2 table` using `joins or Union`.

Now I want to update the record from where it was came actually.

**ex:** grid view contains 2 records:

```
Record1 from t1 table,   
Record2 from t2 table.
```

and now If *record1* wants to update it should be update in `t1` table and *record2* wants to be update it should be update in `t2` table from the same gridview

thanks...

Comment: what you have tried so far? Please put some code here?

Comment: You can see he is new to StackOverflow. Give him advices before taking action...  

I propose that you add a hidden column with the table name of the record data.

Comment: can you explain evenbetter please.. "noobob"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use this idea:
in your select and union statement you can add a string as a column that shows the original Table like this

```
Select ....,'table1' as tableName from table1
union
Select ....,'table2' as tableName from table2
```

and then in the grid you know where it comes from

Comment: thanks RezaRahmati.
I want to edit 1st record from 1st table from the same grid. Is it possible to update ?

Comment: @Krish I am glad that this helps,
if this is what you want you can tag my post as "Answer" by clicking on the checkmark on the left of the post.